# Load select in vue.js

Tags: vue.js

How do I load a select in vue.js before it's visible. So right now I've this:

```
methods: {
    getTypes () {
      TypeService.showAll(1) 
            .then(({ data }) => ({
              types: data.types
          }));
    }
  }
```

Here I receive the types that will be visible in the select like this:

```
  <select v-model="ride.type" class="Radio__admin">
            <option disabled selected>Type?</option>
            <option v-for="type in types" v-bind:value="type.id">
   </select>
```

But when I say:

```
  init () {
    this.getTypes();
  }
```

I get the error:

```
main.js:16526 Uncaught ReferenceError: getTypes is not defined
```

How should I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [documentation](http://vuejs.org/api/#created) methods are first accessible in `created` hook:

> At this stage, the instance has finished processing the options which means the following have been set up: data observation, computed properties, **methods**, watch/event callbacks.